# Undefined variable ao fazer update da Base de dados

Tags: php, sql-update

Estou com um problema ao fazer Update da Base de dados.

```
$AcidenteValidade = $_POST["AcidenteValidade"]; 

$AcidenteAnexo='';
if (isset($_FILES["AcidenteAnexo"]) && $_FILES["AcidenteAnexo"]["name"] != '') {

    $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["AcidenteAnexo"]["tmp_name"]; 

    $fp = fopen($nomeTemporario, 'r'); 
    $AcidenteAnexo = fread($fp, filesize($nomeTemporario)); 
    $AcidenteAnexo = addslashes($AcidenteAnexo);

    fclose($fp); 
}
$consulta2 = "UPDATE tb_trabalhador SET AcidenteAnexo='.$AcidenteAnexo.' WHERE id=$id";
mysql_query($consulta2) or die(mysql_error());
```

O problema é o `AcidenteAnexo` que aparece como:

> Indefinido. Notice: Undefined variable: AcidenteAnexo

Comment: em qual linha ta dando o erro?

Comment: o que aparece se fizer isto: echo $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["AcidenteAnexo"]["tmp_name"];  ???

Comment: A linha de erro é a linha Consulta 2

Comment: então nunca entras no if, certo? 
acho que vc não pode usar apenas $_FILES["AcidenteAnexo"].

Comment: O If serve para eu verificar se existe ou não algum documento alterado

Comment: Revendo isto, editei "update **da** Base de dados" e talvez ficasse melhor "update **na** Base de dados". . . Fica a sugestão pro próximo editor.

Answer (score 1):

A variavel `$AcidenteAnexo` é indefinida porque seu if está retornando false, como ela so começa a existir dentro dele, logo se a condição do if não for satisfeita `$AcidenteAnexo` não vai existir.

```
if (isset($_FILES["AcidenteAnexo"]) && $_FILES["AcidenteAnexo"]["name"] != '') {
    $AcidenteAnexo = addslashes($AcidenteAnexo);
}

$consulta2 = "UPDATE tb_trabalhador SET AcidenteAnexo='$AcidenteAnexo' WHERE id=$id";
mysql_query($consulta2) or die(mysql_error());
```

A **solução** seria colocar o update dentro do if, já que o update será executado sempre que `$_FILES` tiver valor.

O erro pode ser reproduzido de forma simplificada com esse código

```
if(false){
    $nome = 'mario';
}
echo $nome;
```

saida:

```
    Notice: Undefined variable: nome in
```

Comment: Alterei assim como esta na pergunta.
Mas assim não me esta a guardar o $nometemporario

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado Pessoal. Saltava-me um campo ao receber os dados.

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"

$AcidenteAnexo='';
if (isset($_FILES["AcidenteAnexo"]) && $_FILES["AcidenteAnexo"]["name"] != '') {

$nomeTemporario = $_FILES["AcidenteAnexo"]["tmp_name"]; 

$fp = fopen($nomeTemporario, 'r'); 
$AcidenteAnexo = fread($fp, filesize($nomeTemporario)); 
$AcidenteAnexo = addslashes($AcidenteAnexo);

fclose($fp); }
$consulta2 = "UPDATE tb_trabalhador SET AcidenteAnexo='.$AcidenteAnexo.' WHERE id=$id";
mysql_query($consulta2) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Qual campo? poderia descrever melhor como solucionou o problema? sua explicação pode ajudar varias pessoas com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Você não está usando o valor da sua variável no seu update, você tem que mudar para ler o valor da variável.

Está assim:

```
$consulta2 = "UPDATE tb_trabalhador SET AcidenteAnexo='$AcidenteAnexo' WHERE id=$id";
```

O certo seria:

```
$consulta2 = 'UPDATE tb_trabalhador SET AcidenteAnexo=' . $AcidenteAnexo . ' WHERE id=' . $id;
```

Pois assim você concatena os textos do seu update com o valor da variável `$AcidenteAnexo` e do `$id`.